# Assembly segmentation fault after making a system call, at the end of my code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

I was experimenting and have the following assembly code, which works very well, except that I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message right before my program ends:

```
GLOBAL _start

%define ___STDIN 0
%define ___STDOUT 1
%define ___SYSCALL_WRITE 0x04

segment .data
segment .rodata
    L1 db "hello World", 10, 0
segment .bss
segment .text
_start:
    mov eax, ___SYSCALL_WRITE
    mov ebx, ___STDOUT
    mov ecx, L1
    mov edx, 13
    int 0x80
```

It doesn't matter whether or not I have `ret` at the end; I still get the message.

What's the problem?

I'm using x86 and nasm.

Comment: You need to syscall exit explicitly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nasm segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760002/nasm-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Related: [you can't `ret` from `_start`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760002/nasm-segmentation-fault), you have to make a `sys_exit`, `sys_exit_group`, or raise a signal which terminates your process.  Falling off the end of `_start` is a different problem (with the same solution) as trying to use `ret` at the end of `_start`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't `ret` from start; it isn't a function and there's no return address on the stack.  The stack pointer points at `argc` on process entry.

As n.m. said in the comments, the issue is that you aren't exiting the program, so execution runs off into garbage code and you get a segfault.

What you need is:

```
;; Linux 32-bit x86
%define ___SYSCALL_EXIT 1

// ... at the end of _start:
    mov eax, ___SYSCALL_EXIT
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

(The above is 32-bit code.  In 64-bit code you want `mov eax, 231` (exit_group) / `syscall`, with the exit status in EDI.  For example:

```
;; Linux x86-64
    xor   edi, edi     ;  or mov edi, eax    if you have a ret val in EAX
    mov   eax, 231     ; __NR_exit_group
    syscall
```